# Bash script to take screenshot and save the image - Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, capture

I wrote a bash script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a file name"
read filename
import -window root $HOME/Desktop/$filename.png
```

I expected this script to take a screen shot and save the image with the given filename on my desktop.

Problem:  My Ubuntu terminal is giving error:

> import: Command Not Found

Answer (score 9):

You need to install the package [imagemagic](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) to use import command, via Ubuntu Software Center or:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

This will allow you to use `import` command. Also try out **graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat** package.

other alternatives to import are

- `scrot`. Install it with:

  ```
  sudo aptitude install scrot
  ```

  Usage: `scrot screen.png`
- `gnome-screenshot`.  Install it with:

  ```
  sudo aptitude install gnome-screenshot
  ```

Comment: hi devav2...I am getting a message that says -- unable to locate package scrot.. any suggestions

Comment: Prabhu, Try to find the package in Ubuntu Software Center or try changing your software source server to a different one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the best screenshot tool 
[shutter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter) [image: Install shutter]  for use in scripts too! And I believe, this is the most powerful tool and give you most advanced and fine-tuned options to use in scripts.

Install it with the command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

or using the software center *(by clicking the big button below)*

[image: Install via the software center]

And after installation, use this command to take a screenshot of the whole display and save the screenshot in a file named, `myshot.png`

```
shutter -f -o myshot.png -e
```

- The `-f` tells shutter to take a screenshot of the whole display. You could also  use `-a` to take a screenshot of the active window, or tell it to take a shot from any specific window.
- The `-o` option is used for telling shutter the output file name. You could specify any file name
- The `e` option causes shutter to exit after taking the screenshot.

---

The output of `shutter --help` is given below for reference.

```
Usage:
    shutter [options]

Options:
    Example 1
            shutter -a -p=myprofile --min_at_startup

    Example 2
            shutter -s=100,100,300,300 -e

    Example 3
            shutter --window=.*firefox.*

    Example 4
            shutter --web=http://shutter-project.org/ -e

  Capture Mode Options:
    -s, --select=[X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT]
            Capture an area of the screen. Providing X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT is
            optional.

    -f, --full
            Capture the entire screen.

    -w, --window=[NAME_PATTERN]
            Select a window to capture. Providing a NAME_PATTERN (Perl-style
            regex) ist optional.

    -a, --active
            Capture the current active window.

    --section
            Capture a section. You will be able to select any child window
            by moving the mouse over it.

    -m, --menu
            Capture a menu.

    -t, --tooltip
            Capture a tooltip.

    --web=[URL]
            Capture a webpage. Providing an URL ist optional.

    -r, --redo
            Redo last screenshot.

  Settings Options:
    -p, --profile=NAME
            Load a specific profile on startup.

    -o, --output=FILENAME
            Specify a filename to save the screenshot to (overwrites any
            profile-related setting).

            Supported image formats: You can save to any popular image
            format (e.g. jpeg, png, gif, bmp). Additionally it is possible
            to save to pdf, ps or svg.

            Please note: There are several wildcards available, like

             %Y = year
             %m = month
             %d = day
             %T = time
             $w = width
             $h = height
             $name = multi-purpose (e.g. window title)
             $nb_name = like $name but without blanks in resulting strings
             $profile = name of current profile
             $R = random char (e.g. $RRRR = ag4r)
             %NN = counter

            The string is interpretted by strftime. See "man strftime" for
            more examples.

            As an example: shutter -f -e -o './%y-%m-%d_$w_$h.png' would
            create a file named '11-10-28_1280_800.png' in the current
            directory.

  Application Options:
    -h, --help
            Prints a brief help message and exits.

    -v, --version
            Prints version information.

    -d, --debug
            Prints a lot of debugging information to STDOUT.

    --clear_cache
            Clears cache, e.g. installed plugins, at startup.

    --min_at_startup
            Starts Shutter minimized to tray.

    --disable_systray
            Disables systray icon.

    -e, --exit_after_capture
            Exit after the first capture has been made. This is useful when
            using Shutter in scripts.
```

Comment: I love shutter as a GUI app, this is a great detail of the CLI, thanks!

Comment: Shutter is painfully slow at taking a screenshot from command. And it logs a lot of garbage.

BTW I'm using the GUI but for scripting this is inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

To install imagemagick, containing the program `import`, see the other answer. However, you can also launch gnome-screenshot from command line by calling `gnome-screenshot`. The applet will take the screenshot without delay and show a dialog to enter a file name:

[image]

Comment: gnome-screenshot command is working good...Thank you...Is there a way to pass a string argument to this command so that the screenshot is saved with the given string name?

Comment: No, fully automatic screenshots are better done with `import`.

Answer (score 0):

I like `scrot` for this (`apt install scrot`):

```
 #!/bin/bash

 scrot -u -q 100 '/home/stephen/pic/screenshots/screenshot.%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.png'
```

And linked to some key. I ran into issues using the `printscr` key and didn't care enough to investigate.