# Automatic screen capture script

Tags: bash, scripts, screenshot, shutter

I'm looking to accomlish exactly what Anwar Shah describes here [Bash script to take screenshot and save the image - Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202391/bash-script-to-take-screenshot-and-save-the-image-ubuntu)

with the added functionality of setting a time increment for the script to continue taking screen captures. For example, I'd like to be able to execute this script and have it take and export screen shots as jpegs every 5 seconds and continue until I kill the script.

Is there any simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
while sleep 5
do    
    shutter -f -o 'myshot-%T.jpg' -e
done
```

The [`sleep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sleep.1.html) command can take various time durations as arguments: `5s` (or just `5`) for 5 seconds, `129m` for 129 minutes, etc.
The [`shutter`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/shutter.1.html) command supports JPEG output, and the `%T` tells Shutter to automatically replace that part with the time of the script.
 (There's also `%NN` to tell Shutter to use a counter.)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you muru, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In my `.bashrc`, I define a function, `screenshot` to use ImageMagik:
    screenshot ()
    {
        import -window root ~/var/screenshot/$(tshhmmss)_screendump.png
    }

and, for the timestamp,

```
alias tshhmmss='date +%y%b%d-%H%M%S'
```

Then, wrapping it in `while sleep 5 ...` is easy.