# gnome-screenshot problem with color depth 8, any change to generate screenshots 32 color depth?

Tags: unity, command-line, screenshot, color-depth, gnome-screenshot

```
$ gnome-screenshot -f test.png
$ identify test.png
test.png PNG 1920x1080 1920x1080+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 275KB 0.000u 0:00.000
$ xwininfo -root | grep Depth
  Depth: 24
```

It generates 8-bit images, but I want 24-bit depth screenshots.

I need to generate high quality screenshots, any idea?

I did look into `--help` and `--help-all` and `--help-gtk` parameters of `gnome-screenshot`

Comment: I think it specifies the depth per channel. Since there are three channels, ie R,G and B, the total depth is 24.

Answer (score 1):

I got this hint from [Bash script to take screenshot and save the image - Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202391/bash-script-to-take-screenshot-and-save-the-image-ubuntu). I alternatively used imagemagick and vary the depth using the following ([hint from here on imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#depth)).

> -depth value
>
> depth of the image.
>
> This the number of bits in a color sample within a pixel. Use this
>   option to specify the depth of raw images whose depth is unknown such
>   as GRAY, RGB, or CMYK, or to change the depth of any image after it
>   has been read.

Comment: imagemagick import subjectively brings better image quality even without quality argument and -define png arguments, more details in answer below

Answer (score 1):

`imagemagick import` subjectively brings much better image quality even without quality arguments (or `-define png:` arguments)

but it indeed shows 8-bit depth:

```
$ import -depth 24 -window root test.png
$ identify test.png
  test.png PNG 1920x1080 1920x1080+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 359KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

But the picture is of much better quality than with `gnome-screenshot`

I have to figure out how best to define the png parameters for import (I want lossless compression) but I think it might be for another question.

`import` might be buggy. Another possibility might be `shutter`, but it has far fewer command line arguments